# GoRelic - Trace Metric Explanation

Tags: go, newrelic

I have added a trace in a Go function using the GoRelic as mentioned [here](https://github.com/yvasiyarov/gorelic#tracing-metrics). The numbers reported in GoRelic Dashboard for this trace are as follows:- (Please check the screen shot of the trace in NewRelic dashboard [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwE7aDgG6P0DZm9mQTZucUFRZ3M/view?usp=sharing))

Trace/ Prudsys Select/ max Average ms

```
Avg - 9.38k ms
Total - 37.5k ms
Max - 13.9k ms
Min - 5.48k ms
StdDev - 3.93k
Rate - 20.8 ms/sec
Count - 4 Samples
```

Can some one explain me:-

1. What does k ms mean in 9.38k ms? Does it mean 9 sec 38ms?
2. What does Rate - 20.8 ms/sec mean?
3. What does max Average ms mean in "Trace/Prudsys Select/ max Average
   ms"?
4. What does count - 4 Samples mean?

Comment: Hi Tuk, I just started using gorelic, and tracing code blocks, but I cound't find the metrics trace anywhere in the newrelic plugin dashboard? How did you get to that chart?
Thank you

Comment: Hi Song, After logging in on top right corner where user name is showing, click on "Account Settings" then from the left Select "Connected Agents", then on the "Connected Agents" page you can find the various applications using GoRelic plugin all will have the perfix "GoRelic". Click on any of them and you will land up on the metrics page. After that you can click on any of the metrics to get the graphs I have mentioned in my question